# Printing a grid made using CSS gradient to a pdf (in either Chrome or Firefox)

Tags: html, css, pdf, browser, background-image

I am creating a dotted grid in CSS using the `background-image` property and `repeating-linear-gradient` like this

```
:root{
  --c0: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  --c: grey;
  --point-size: 1pt;
  --cell-size: 0.5cm;
}
.dotted{
  background-color: var(--c);
  background-image:
  repeating-linear-gradient(
    white,
    white calc(var(--cell-size) - var(--point-size)),
    var(--c0) calc(var(--cell-size) - var(--point-size)),
    var(--c0) var(--cell-size)),
  repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,
    white,
    white calc(var(--cell-size) - var(--point-size)),
    var(--c0) calc(var(--cell-size) - var(--point-size)),
    var(--c0) var(--cell-size));
}
```

which looks like perfectly fine in the browser (both Chrome & Firefox)
[image]

But if I try to print it in a .pdf it doesn't works (both Chrome & Firefox).

If I use Firefox to output the .pdf, it looks empty in the basic Ubuntu document viewer, however if I open this .pdf in Chrome it has a moiré effect like this (here with a bigger `--point-size` to make the effect more obvious)
[image]

If I use Chrome to output the .pdf, it looks pixelated in the basic Ubuntu document viewer or in Chrome.
[image]

I need it to looks a lot more crisp and regular than this.

I tried different alternatives, like using `background-repeat` with a limited `background-size` so I can transform the `repeating-linear-gradient` into a `linear-gradient` like so

```
.dotted{
  background-color: var(--c);
  background-image:
  linear-gradient(
    white,
    white calc(var(--cell-size) - var(--point-size)),
    var(--c0) calc(var(--cell-size) - var(--point-size)),
    var(--c0) var(--cell-size)),
  linear-gradient(90deg,
    white,
    white calc(var(--cell-size) - var(--point-size)),
    var(--c0) calc(var(--cell-size) - var(--point-size)),
    var(--c0) var(--cell-size));
  background-size: var(--cell-size) var(--cell-size);
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Or trying to output from the browser printing window and the system printing window and see if there are any differences for both Chrome and Firefox.
They all give slightly different results but either has a moiré or pixelated effect, or is just an all white or grey background.

It seems to me this is due to browsers guessing it has to use a low DPI to render the `background-image` and then doing approximations which ends-up in either the moiré or pixelated effect depending on which browser or systems you use to print it. But I have no idea on how I can get control over this.

Also changing the units from `pt` and `cm` to `px` gives much cleaner results (probably less approximations to do by the browser when it's rendering the `background-image`) but because this is for printing on actual paper I need the grid to repeat exactly every `0.5cm`.

How can I make either Chrome or Firefox render this grid properly?

Answer (score 0):

Mon Dieu, that's a nightmare way to build a PDF (took me several attempts to hone it down)

[image]

The key is to work in default common units and I am still not sure if I have it good enough.
[image]

Whilst Acrobat should accept it
[image]

Other viewers may not understand that unusual PDF structure,

My final adjustment:- is to say keep all units as uniform in pixels, for good all round rendering. It works fairly well either as points or pixels, however, keep all units the same. Here it is in Edge (Chrome based) at 200%
[image]

The key issue is keeping close to default screen pixel size, which naturally varies from user app to user and app and monitors. The best solution would be PNG image at 96 dpi its more "Portable" and just as scalable as thousands of lines, plus much faster to display.

```
<style type="text/css">
:root{
  --c: red;
  --gap-size: 21px;
  --cell-size: 24px;
}
body{
  width: 793px;
  height: 1123px;
  background-color: white;
  background-image:
  repeating-linear-gradient(
    white 0px var(--gap-size),
    transparent var(--gap-size) var(--cell-size)),
  repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,
    white 0px var(--gap-size),
    var(--c) var(--gap-size) var(--cell-size));
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks you for the answer. When you say default unit what do you mean exactly? Since in CSS you have to precise a unit i'm not sure to understand. If I understood your solution correctly, you mean keeping the cell-size and the point-size in the same unit either px or pt should work? But then I'm not able to have a cell-size of exactly 0.5cm - because I've to convert it to an integer in either px or pt which causes rounding approximations - which is needed in my case. Also I did not understood what do you mean by "keeping close to default screen pixel size".

Comment: Also i'm interested by the sofware in your first screenshot, is it something to look at the generated pdf structure?